# In an "Always On" architecture, how are duplicate concurrent transactions handled?

Tags: architectural-patterns, enterprise-architecture

Imagine a scenario where a gift card has been purchased with cash, the gift card is duplicated, and each card is used to purchase an iPad at a self-service counter at exactly the same time.

What are the possible ways to prevent or mitigate this duplicate transaction in an Always On architecture?

I have come up with:

- Preferential routing based on the gift card ID (is that ever done in practice?)
- Maximum amount limits on gift cards to make the loss sustainable
- Requiring high-value purchases to be made at a serviced counter, thereby making the concurrency unlikely.

Are there are other software approaches that could be taken?

Comment: This very much depends on situational factors such as the size of the company, the geographical distance between stores, the number of daily purchases (both per store and global), the number of daily gift card uses, the budget available for a high availability global database, and the projected losses due to this kind of gift card duplication. This isn't about finding the correct answer, it's about finding a balance between what's truly necessary and what has a reasonable cost, and you need to see the big picture to make such a call.

Comment: Yes, I'm more interested in what options are available in an architect's bag of tricks before having to move away from an Always On architecture.

Comment: Was wondering how this was handled in VISA, and they're very cagey with technical details. In 2000s it seems to have been a giant IBM mainframe presumably running DB2. https://www.computerworld.com/article/2584171/when-five-9s-aren-t-enough.html

Answer (score 3):

In theory, use a global database with full ACID properties (i.e. SQL):

```
update gift_cards
set redeemed = 1
where
  gift_card_id = 'cf03a074-45a7-43aa-b800-d33e01af006b' and
  redeemed = 0
```

The database guarantees that only one of the updates will succeed due to the `redeemed = 0` clause. The application code detects the failure and rejects one of the transactions.

In practice, there is a non-trivial cost to running a truly global SQL database, in terms of all of latency, uptime and actual dollars. The business will have to make a trade-off if the losses due to dual spending are greater than that cost.

Comment: Note the additional complexity that gift cards generally allow being redeemed more than once (as long as there's money on there), which somewhat complicates the example. That being said, the overall core of the answer is correct.

Comment: You would not even need a global database, as long as a specific gift card specifies a single server to handle the redemption.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great option.  Do you have any global database product names?  I could only find Amazon Aurora, which claims a 1s write transaction time coast-to-coast.

Comment: @Paul databases generally don't care anything about where they're deployed nor the geographic location of their clients - that's really more of an IT networking/infrastructure concern.

Comment: @JonasH Always On needs to be scalable and fault tolerant

Comment: @Paul Once again, you need to work out the tradeoffs you're going to make between latency, uptime and cost. Every major database engine, whether SQL or otherwise, has some form of replication.

Answer (score 0):

A common consistency model is [ACID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) that guarantees things like consistency. But it has downsides. It needs a central authority to determine the actual state. This is not always possible, for example if two connected regions are disconnected, there is no possible way for both regions maintain service while keeping consistency.

Another model is Eventual consistency, or [BASE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency). This could either accept the loss for duplicate redemption, or solve the conflict at a later date, for example by crediting the coupon value only when the consistency can be guaranteed.

There is no way to gain the benefit of both ACID and BASE models. You have to chose what properties you want to sacrifice.